# How to choose for multithreading - c

Tags: c, multithreading

I have to do a program client-server in c where server can use n-threads that can work simultaneously for manage the request of clients.

For do it I use a socket that use a listener that put the new FD (of new connection request) in a list and then the threads can take it when they are able to do.

I know that I can use pipe too for communication between thread.

Is the socket the best way ? And why or why not?

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Are you using sockets to communicate between threads or the client and the server? The threads can communicate just using some shared memory and proper synchronization primitives.

Comment: You can use libevent. It is tested, optimized for performance and works under different platforms.

Comment: I use socket for communication between clients and server

Answer (score 1):

To communicate between threads you can use socket as well as shared memory.
To do multithreading there are many libraries available on github, one of them I used is the below one.
***https://github.com/snikulov/prog_posix_threads/blob/master/workq.c***

I tried and tested the same way what you want. it works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

There's one very nice resource related to socket multiplexing which I think you should stop and read after reading this answer. That resource is entitled [The C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html), and it details numerous solutions to the problem people faced in the year 2000, of handling 10000 clients.

Of those solutions, multithreading is not the primary one. Indeed, multithreading as an optimisation should be one of *your last resorts*, as that optimisation will interfere with the instruments you use to diagnose other optimisations.

In general, here is how you should perform optimisations, in order to provide guaranteed justifications:

1. **Use a profiler** to determine the most significant bottlenecks (in your single-threaded program).
2. **Perform your optimisation** upon one of the more significant bottlenecks.
3. **Use the profiler again**, with the same set of data, to verify that your optimisation worked correctly.

You can repeat these steps ad infinitum until you decide the improvements are no longer *tangible* (meaning, good luck observing the differences between before and after). Following these steps will provide you with data you can show your employer, if he/she asks you what you've been doing for the last hour, so **make sure you save the output of your profiler at each iteration.**

Optimisations are per-machine; what this means is that **an optimisation for your machine might actually be slower on another machine**. For example, you may use a buffer of 4096 bytes for your machine, while the cache lines for another machine might indicate that 512 bytes is a better idea.

Hence, ideally, we should **design programs and modules in such a way that their resources are minimal and can be easily be scaled up, substituted and/or otherwise adjusted for other machines**. This can be difficult, as it means in the *buffer* example above you might start off with a *buffer* of one byte; you'd most likely need to study *finite state machines* to achieve that, and using buffers of *one byte* might not always be technically feasable (i.e. when dealing with fields that are guaranteed to be a certain width; you should use that width as your minimum limit, and scale up from there). The reward is ultra-portable and ultra-optimisable in all situations.

Keep in mind that *extra threads* use *extra resources*; we tend to assume that the stack space reserved for a thread can grow to 1MB, so 10000 sockets occupying 10000 threads (in a thread-per-socket model) would occupy about 10GB of memory! Yikes! The *minimal resources* method suggests that we should **start off with one thread, and scale up from there, using a multithreading profiler to measure performance** like in the three steps above.

I think you'll find, though, that for anything purely socket-driven, you likely won't need more than *one* thread, even for 10000 clients, if you study [the C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) or use some library which has been engineered based on those findings (see your comments for one such suggestion). We're not talking about masses of number crunching, here; we're talking about socket operations, which the kernel likely processes using a single core, and so you can likely match that single core with a single thread, and avoid any *context switching* or *thread synchronisation* troubles/overheads incurred by multithreading.